# Firestore permission denied even with rules set to allow all

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a simple React application that uses firebase as the backend. It was working fine until 2 hours ago when it started giving "code=permission-denied" on data reads. It does start working randomly for 2-4 minutes every once in a while. I have not made any significant changes to the firebase configurations that might cause this. PS authentication is working fine.

This is the error message I am getting:

> firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.5.2): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here are my firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my line of code that is generating this call to firestore:

```
const userRef = collection(firebaseDB, "teams");
          const q = query(userRef, where("email", "==", user.email));
          unSubUser = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const data = doc.data();
                dispatch(setTeamDetails({
                 // ...setting data
                }))
              });
            } else {
              // some app related actions
            }
```

Comment: More information: https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/JH8hiSsfnSZHMdZqFTaC

Answer (score 7):

*firebaser here*

**Update** 18:49 pst: the issue has been resolved. The problem was caused by a mismatched rollout in the upstream identity an auth services. Also see our [update in this Twitter/X thread](https://twitter.com/Firebase/status/1725639389521326176).

There seems to be an outage at the moment that likely causes the problem you're seeing. The engineering team has identified the cause of the problem and is mitigating it now.

You can track the status at the top of the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/) and on this specific [status for Firebase Authentication](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/JH8hiSsfnSZHMdZqFTaC) and for [status for Cloud Firestore](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/iRvJVnsbz8T47ySiy5Hg#PsdLE8rUi9SeXTKz6wWy).

Comment: Where can we read the cause of this issue?

Comment: Hey Omar. We're working on an update explaining what happened. I'll post an update here too once I can.