# firestore/permission-denied. The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation react native expo

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Am developing react native app when I change my security rule I get the above error. I follow almost all the solution to the similar questions but am still getting this error. Here is my code

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const userId = user.uid;

      await firestore()
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((userSnapshot) => {
         //console.log("User exists: ", userSnapshot.exists);

          if (userSnapshot.exists) {
          //console.log("User data: ", userSnapshot.data());
            setProfile(userSnapshot.data());
            setLoading(false);
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e.message);
        });
    };
    if (user) fetchUser();
  }, [user]);
```

This is my firebase security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

     match /Users/{userId=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null
     }
   // I even remove this code but still getting the same error
     match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    
  }
}
```

Please help as am stuck here.

Comment: Most likely you're affect by an outage. I wrote more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341

Answer (score 0):

1. **Rule Specificity:** Your rule for /Users/{userId} looks correct,
   assuming that userId in Firestore matches the uid of the
   authenticated user. Double-check that user.uid in your React Native
   app corresponds exactly to the userId in your Firestore document
   paths.
2. **Debugging Rules:** Use the Firestore Rules Simulator in the Firebase
   Console. It allows you to simulate reads and writes to see if your
   rules are working as expected.
3. **Error Logging:** In your catch block, log the entire error object, not
   just e.message. Sometimes, more detailed error information is
   available in other parts of the error object.
4. **User Authentication:** Ensure the user is properly authenticated and
   user.uid is not null or undefined when you're trying to access
   Firestore.
5. **Rule Propagation Time:** After updating rules in Firebase, it might
   take a few minutes for the changes to propagate. Ensure you've
   waited a sufficient amount of time after changing the rules.