# In flutter firebase, I get the error: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Please help me understand what the issue is! Today I just went on my app and I was getting this error. I didn't change anything and then this error started showing up on my friends beta testing phones. Please help! I literally did nothing and my rules are set to always true.

[image]

As you can see, the rules work perfectly fine.

Comment: Most likely you're affect by an outage. I wrote more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** The issue with Cloud Firestore, Identity and Access Management, Identity Platform has been resolved for all affected users as of Wednesday, 2023-11-15 18:42 US/Pacific.

---

I'm experiencing the same problem in several apps that use Firestore and apparently the error is in Google Cloud, you can follow their solution here: https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/iRvJVnsbz8T47ySiy5Hg

Comment: Oh wow. So its just happening to everyone right now...

Thanks for letting me know! Does this happen often?

Comment: This is the first time I've seen it happen and I've been using Firestore for a few years.

Comment: Same, never seen it happen before in 3 years. It's happening to my production app as well

Comment: Same here, I hope Google solve it soon because many apps in productions depend of this awesome service :)