# Firestore database data lost problem(The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the last 12 hours, I lost some data in Firestore Database. Did you encounter such a situation? What do you think?

2 days ago there was some problems in Firebase servers.

[In flutter firebase, I get the error: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491512/in-flutter-firebase-i-get-the-error-cloud-firestore-permission-denied-the-ca)

May it be related with this problem? What do you think? How can I bring my 12 hours data?

Comment: While Firebase databases in a certain location were unavailable to mobile/web users in the outage on November 15, no data was lost during that time. Without a specific description of what actually happened, it's impossible to say more about your specific problem.

Comment: I am using counter in my app(in collection field), it is increased every button tap. Interestingly it was decreased in the last 12 hours. It was impossible to be decreased, I am always increasing. Then I thought that this was may be related with firebase servers as it is very hard to explain with another reason.

Comment: In fact, I did not lost a collection field data but I lost user transaction, my counter was 225, it was decreased to 217, interestingly...

Comment: I am using reference.update method to update my data.

Comment: Firestore is an immediately consistent database. Once the write was executed on the server, it is visible to all clients and won't be rolled back. We'd need to look at all parts involved and see a [reasonable repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to investigate/speculate further. If you want to do that, I recommend updating your question with the necessary default (there's a tiny `edit` link right under it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using `Firebase Transactions`. When multiple users was updating same value at the same time I was encountering this problem. It seemed like that I lost data but not, I just implemented my code wrongly.

For counters in Firebase, we should use `Firebase Transactions` to prevent such a problems.

Using `Firebase Transactions` will solve my problem I think.

**Solution:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?hl=en