# Suddenly getting Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I've quadruple checked my firebase rules and everything is correct:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

Everything was working prior, and then suddenly I started receiving these errors. The only thing that has happened is someone else had logged into the firebase account, but nothing has changed. I'm very confused what's happening and why my react-native app is suddenly unable to call firebase utilities.

Comment: Most likely you're affect by an outage. I wrote more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341