# Firebase Firestore issue to get data, PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have project that is live now all my apps are off
the apps are to manage stores

the app was working for 3 years without such breakdowns
today the app was off due to an issue

```
E/flutter (15104): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

the issue happens when the user login, then sends a request to get the data which will give this error

yet after doing let's say  getting data without login, I can get the data

Comment: Check your firestore security rules as well as the database access rules.

Comment: Same with me.  Oddly my web based version works fine as does the android emulator.

Comment: Most likely you're affected by an outage. I shared more details about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341