# Firestore does not have permission

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I built an app that relies on Firebase for the backend, it has been working properly for the past few weeks, this morning like an hour ago I decided to work on the project and the app is not storing data in Cloud Firestore. I keep getting errors that the client does not have permission but in the rules, I have declared read, and write to be true. What do I do?

[image: The Error I Keep Getting]

[image: My Firestore rule]

Comment: Most likely you're affect by an outage. I wrote more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341

Comment: I’ll try it today hopefully it works thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/iRvJVnsbz8T47ySiy5Hg
Summary: Some Cloud Firestore customers experiencing permission denied errors when reading and writing to their database.
I'm having the same problem and it's affecting my app. I'm waiting for them to find a solution.