# React-Firebase:--Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I created a login function which uses the **signInWithPopup** function provided by firebase to log the user into the website. When the user is authenticated, it checks if the user is in the users collection in my firestore. If yes, only the username and photo fields are updated. If no, the user is will be create. Everything was working perfectly even after I updated my security rules. Just this evening i started receiving the following error.

`Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Below is my log in function:

```
const login = async () => {
    await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    setUser(user);
    try {
      const userRef = doc(db, "users", user.email);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.email), {
          user_name: user.displayName,
          user_photo: user.photoURL,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("userType", docSnap.data().user_type);
        setUserType(docSnap.data().user_type);
      } else {
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.email), {
          user_name: user.displayName,
          user_mail: user.email,
          user_photo: user.photoURL,
          user_type: "teamMember",
          user_level: 1,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("userType", "teamMember");
        setUserType("teamMember");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

So i changed my rules back to:
 `match /users/{userId}{allow read, write: if true;}`

But the error still occurs.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Most likely you're affect by an outage. I wrote more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341