# Firebase Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've had a website in production for a year now, and permissions have never been a problem. All of a sudden today, I get the following error upon the first database query on the dashboard.

[image]

Authentication is still working, as I'm able to log in and retrieve the currentUser.

Every thread about this issue mentions the firebase rules, but I seem to still have the issue no matter what I change them to. For context, here they are currently:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a plan B for solving this problem?

Comment: Most likely you're affect by an outage. I wrote more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341

Comment: Guess I'll monitor that. Thank you!