# Missing or insufficient permissions. FirebaseError:

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on this React social media clone app from "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELyjd5OXZKI&t=11879s"; I keep getting this error:

ERROR
Missing or insufficient permissions.
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I tried changing my permission rule to:
" allow read, write: if true;"

But it still did not work. I was also following a YouTube video that said the problem can be fixed by adding:
"allow read, write: if request.time > timestamp.date(2020, 9, 10);".

It still did not work for me either.

The last one I had that was working was:
"    allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 12, 7);"

If I add that right now, it still won't work for me. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Most likely you're affect by an outage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all

Comment: So what i am understanding is this happens often and the team works on fixing it? Is there like a ticket i need to submit, or they just fix it?

Comment: You are always free to reach out to Firebase support with your concerns about anything related to Firebase. https://firebase.google.com/support