# Firebase storage authentication issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Some users of the web app I'm developing are having issues with accessing Firebase storage. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is but looking on their browser dev tools it seems that they get a series of 302 - moved temporarily responses from firebasestorage.googleapis.com and in some of them the Authentication header gets lost. I'm using the web SDK version 9.

It only happens to some of the users, I was not able to reproduce the issue myself.

These are my storage rules and cors configurations, after few tries, in case they matter

Firebase Storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

CORS config file:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://my-web-app"],
      "method": ["GET", "POST", "HEAD", "PUT", "DELETE"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

On some clients listAll from the web SDK version nine gets a 402 forbidden response for firebase, though the rules are quite simple. User was authenticated. Was expecting to get the list of files. I was not able to reproduce the issue using different computer and browsers.

Anything wrong I might be doing with the configurations?

I don't think it's related to the outage as this question is about firebase storage, while the outage only affected firestore. Can this question please be reopened? I keep havint this issue after the outage was resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Most likely you're affect by an outage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all