# Firebase/Firestore - "Missing or insufficient permissions."

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore

Today I got on an app that I am developing that was an old build and seemed to put the Firestore Database in a weird state. Now I get the following error after that happened. As of yesterday I did not have this issue.

`Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing or insufficient permissions.}`

I know this is a common problem. I have seen the solution to set the `Rules` section in the Firestore Database section. I have done that with the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;   
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried to Unenforce the App Check, which it already is.

Is there anything else to look at for consideration?

Comment: Most likely you were affect by an outage. I wrote more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - it looks like this has been fixed from the status page, but I am still getting the error. is there a time delay and should i check later?

Comment: Nope, it should be fixed for all users. I'm not sure what else could be goign on.

Comment: Got it, the debug token was updated