# Fatal Exception: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

## PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

**com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException**

I have several android apps on google playstore that use **Firestore** as the backend. All the apps have large number of DAU. They have been working perfectly fine for a long time, but last night, I noticed a spike in crash reports in Firebase Crashlytics dashboard. All of them had the same exception:

`Fatal Exception: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

The strange thing is that this exception occurred in multiple apps at the same time, **between 01:00 AM and 07:00 AM (UTC+5)**, and then stopped. I have **not changed anything in the code or the Firestore rules** recently. I have **tried to reproduce the issue** on my devices, but **everything works as expected**. I have also checked the Firestore usage and quota, and they are well below the limits.

Here are some screenshots from the **Firebase Crashlytics dashboard** showing the crash reports:

**App with original class names:**
[image]

**App with obfuscated class names**
[image]

Here's the Stack Trace:

```
Caused by com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(Util.java:112)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(EventManager.java:166)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.removeAndCleanupTarget(SyncEngine.java:596)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(SyncEngine.java:432)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.MemoryComponentProvider$RemoteStoreCallback.handleRejectedListen(MemoryComponentProvider.java:104)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(RemoteStore.java:581)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:465)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(RemoteStore.java:57)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(RemoteStore.java:180)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:109)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(WatchStream.java:38)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1$com-google-firebase-firestore-remote-AbstractStream$StreamObserver(AbstractStream.java:119)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(:4)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(AbstractStream.java:67)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(AbstractStream.java:110)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(FirestoreChannel.java:140)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:661)
       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:646)
       at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
       at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:234)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I am wondering what could have caused this **Permission Denied Exception** in multiple apps at the same time, and how to prevent it from happening again. Is it possible that there was some temporary issue with the Firebase servers or the network connectivity?
Has anyone else experienced this issue?

I have tried to reproduce the issue but I haven't been able to do so.

Comment: Sajid jan, try to look at the link I have provided, the exception is being thrown is the same as you got

I mean it's problem of rules although I understand that you didn't change the rules, it may be other person that have access to the project or may be some bug at the side of firestore - but it's permission(rules) problem

Comment: Well, it's obvious that it's a rules problem. But this particular incident that occurred in my multiple apps wasn't a human error(No one else has got any access to my firebase accounts). It's a bug or something else on Google's end and that's what I am trying to find out.
That question you mentioned, and the underlying answers address the Rules issue on developer's end. While this particular incident happened under different circumstances and should be addressed differently.

Comment: ok deleting first comment

Comment: Most likely happened because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341).