# In flutter firebase, I get the error: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission

Tags: flutter, firebase

In flutter firebase, I get the error: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Please help me understand what the issue is! Today I just went on my app and I was getting this error. I didn't change anything and then this error started showing up on my friends beta testing phones. Please help! I literally did nothing and my rules are set to always true.

rules_version = '2';service cloud.firestore {match /databases/{database}/documents {match /{document=**} {allow read, write: if true;}}}

As you can see, the rules work perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe it was because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491268/firestore-permission-denied-even-with-rules-set-to-allow-all/77491341#77491341).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).